# How can I find ROI and detect markers inside?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm a beginner in computer vision. I have a question about detection and tracking. I want to detect the white rectangle in the image below, to determine the interesting area and to detect the contour of the red markers.

But I don't want to make use of color information to detect the markers.

Can anyone give me suggestions on how to do this?

[image: Example image]

Comment: The question is a bit vague. A simple transform to 1 bit Black&White would be sufficient for this simple case, but presumably not what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the contours with `CvFindContours` and use `CvApproxPoly()` to find the rectangle. You can find a good example of how to use this function to find rectangles [here](http://www.aishack.in/2010/01/an-introduction-to-contours/) and adapt it to your situation. To find the circles I would advise to do something with the ratio between the arcLength and the area of the contours you find as for circles this ratio is very specific. To find the arcLength use `cvArcLength(CvSeq* c)` to find the area use `cvContourArea(CvSeq* c)` while going through the contours in a for loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just detect the circles, an adapted [Hough Tranfrom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) should work.

Comment: Thank you Zac, but I wanna to detect both white part and circle inside Especially, white part is my interesting area and red dot is my tracking marker. :)

Comment: Edge detect & standard Hough transform to detect straight lines, then build the quadrilateral from that.  I think there may be adaptations of the hough to detect squares - but I'm guessing you want to be skew invariant.

Comment: Let's me try, I will ask you again :). Thank you for your reply.