# Which technique that can I execute and get output of same function in same time?

Tags: c++, image-processing, parallel-processing

According to the previous question [How can I find ROI and detect markers inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553332/how-can-i-find-roi-and-detect-markers-inside), thank you for professional who's help me. I have already done that task. :)

My next question that related with previously,
Now I would like to track each blob individually by call the detecting function (named track(param)) with different parameters (as blobs number) in same time then functions will return me the output of blob position.

Which techniques that can I execute same function in the same time?
I have confused about [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/about-openmp/), [OpenCL](http://www.khronos.org/opencl/) and some parallel programming that possible to return output on the same time or not?

Sorry for poorly in English. Thank you for all of helpers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you just need multi-threading, which can be done by a library such as [Boost Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/thread.html). You can spawn multiple threads to track each blob. You can then use join in the end to ensure all threads are completed and combine the results

Comment: Thank you for answer, actually what is difference between OpenMP and Boost Thread. And Can I use OpenCL in this situation?

Comment: OpenCL and OpenMP seem to be more geared towards having multiple processors (or multiple systems), which is a bit overkill for your situation. Threads are useful for multicore processors (which are dominant in desktop computers currently).